Charged capacitor inertia
A charged capacitor has a greater energy content with respect to an uncharged one, so its mass is slightly greater, due to the mass-energy equivalence. Then, it will take a slightly higher force to accelerate it. Is there an intuitive thought experiment to justify this, at least qualitatively?

Please explain what you mean by "intuitive thought experiment"? What do you want to justify?

I'd say that you have more or less given a thought experiment already. You've applied physical laws to a particular case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force

Not sure if thought experiment is the right term, but this effect (increased inertial mass) can be explained in terms of internal EM forces.
This additional EM force is the EM force due to acceleration of the charges (mostly due to the electric part of the EM field).
It can be derived from Maxwell's equations and boundary conditions, that electric field due to an accelerated charged particle has a component proportional to its acceleration. When many charged particles of the same sign form a compact body (charged body) and accelerate together, these electric field components of all particles act back on the particles, and the whole body experiences net force proportional to acceleration of the body. This force acts against the acceleration:
$$
\mathbf F_{acc} = -k\mathbf a
$$
with positive $k$. The constant $k$ turns out to be proportional to the Coulomb potential energy of the body (different distributions could have different constant of proportionality). If the system was made of both positive and negative particles, $k$ could be negative.
When we put this force into the equation of motion of the body made up of particles with masses $m_b$ (assuming non-relativistic motions, and all particles in the body moving with the same acceleration $\mathbf a$):
$$
\sum_b m_b \mathbf a = \mathbf F_{ext} + \mathbf F_{acc},
$$
$$
\sum_b m_b\mathbf a = \mathbf F_{ext} - k\mathbf a.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\left(\sum_b m_b+k\right)\mathbf a = \mathbf F_{ext}.
$$
Thus the acceleration-dependent component of the electric field increases the effective inertial mass of the body (as judged by the acceleration effect of the external forces $\mathbf F_{ext}$), above the sum of masses of the charged particles. This added mass due to EM interaction is sometimes called electromagnetic mass (but beware, this term may be used with different meanings).

Thank you, this was exactly the interpretation I was looking for. But now consider the case of a superconductive loop (zero resistance) with some current flowing in it. The system has an additional intertial mass due to the energy stored in the magnetic field. How can we justify the increased resistance to acceleration, in this case?

@AndreaBalestrero that's a different question (although the interactions and the answer may be similar), so you can post it as a new question.
